# If I set the school to "School A" then only School A's classes should be visible

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, data-validation

I have created a progress tracker for the Academy Trust I work in. The trust at the moment consist of 4 schools.  Students move between the schools as the progress and between classes during the year depending on their abilities and needs.  when a student move his/her tracking data needs to move to the correct class because teachers does not want to search.

My idea is to just change the class and then the students whole data row should move automatically to the correct class on another sheet.

The first thing I need to do is to be able to select the class from a drop down list but the list must be linked to the school.  So if I set the school to "School A" then only School A's classes should be visible. The same for school B,C and D.

The Script I tried is below.
It is not working and due to the fact that I do not know anything about Scripts I do not know how to fix this problem. I got the Script from Youtube and tried to edit it to fit my workbook.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SIN5NyQ9fw&t=27s
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aOn0VMgG1w

  - [The Script](https://script.google.com/a/hornbeamacademytrust.com/macros/d/MGo_5uvg87HBX62n5wjZXM4eeCcJJxTZN/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvHDV6h-A4U4LB0Y4Yz18tGExn6spQHtFguL-ogoGMNwxbdMefekW9Y4mw7bLRbESEpByM7rXivzlJrwMD_B2peuPxfiWuQ8UdArjQVsylkIj8wyuDo1Vuab18Sd8oUYKXCUEh09gUg)
  - [The Work book](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QruJvWeKjZ0s5TTWPHJN5OJ5M3OD4Dhk9xdHaXV7SVw/edit#gid=1663170448)

```
function onEdit(){
  var tabLists = "lists";
  var tabValidation = "w1";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("lists")

  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();

  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && ActiveCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getSheetName() == tabValidation){
    activeCell.offset(0,1).clearContent().clearDataValidations()

    var Sites = datass.getRange(1,6,datass.getLastColumn()).getvalue();

    var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) +1;
    if(makeindex != 0){

        var validationRange = datass.getRange(3, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);



    }
  }
    }
```

Comment: What Youtube video? Do you modified something of the original script? Where do you get stuck? Did you get an error message?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SIN5NyQ9fw

Comment: I tried to change the names of the sheets but when I run the Script the Logs does not pick up anything

Comment: the Script is under sorting Hat

Comment: What is "sorting Hat"? Please [edit] the question to add all the relevant details to it. The video title says that it's about dependent drop-downs, that isn't conditional formatting (change cell background/fonts ).

Comment: when you look at the work book you will see 4 schools each with a number of classes.  sheet 1W is the first class of school a.  I want to (at the end) to select a school and then a class and the sheets will then move the student to the correct class (the row with all the students data in it) but to do that I need to be able to select the relevant class.  what I wan t the script to do is when I select school A in column K5 then a drop down list of all of school A's classes should show up in L5.  I created a script from that video and if you open the script editor the script is under Sorting Hat

Comment: As I mentioned on my previous comment, please [edit] the question to add all the relevante details to it, and if the script is short, include it on the question too. If the script is large, then add the main parts to the question.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Yes, it's better, but it's missing the mention of where do you get stuck / the textual error message.

Answer (score 0):

One of the errors, `var tabValidation = "w1";` is that the spreadsheet doesn't contain a sheet named `w1` but there is one named `1W`.

Other errors, maybe a typos, are

- `ActiveCell.getRow()`.
- `datass.getRange(1,6,datass.getLastColumn()).getvalue()`

Bear in mind that Google Apps Script / JavaScript spelling is important, in other words, `w` is not the same than `W`, `ActiveCell` is not the same as `activeCell` and `getvalue` is not the same as `getValue`.

Please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting to learn some tools and techniques to find the above problems.

Comment: I have changed w1 to 1W but now the script won't save.   ReferenceError:"ActiveCell" is not defined. (line9,"Sorting Hat")

Comment: @MielieJonker I already mentioned ActiveCell <- The correct spelling is activeCell.

Comment: I fixed all the spelling errors you have mentioned.  The script saves now but does not work on the workbook

Comment: @MielieJonker Have you already read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting ?

Comment: No I am busy with that.

Comment: Ok. Read it. Is there anything specific you want me to focus on?

Comment: Read this [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089041/1595451) Then try to figure what is wrong with your current script.